# Interesting problem on "neighbor fractions"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, fractions

This is from I. M. Gelfand's *Algebra* book.

> Fractions $\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{c}{d}$ are called
> neighbor fractions if their difference $\displaystyle\frac{ad - bc}{bd}$ has numerator of $\pm 1$,
> that is, $ad - bc = \pm 1$. Prove that
>
> **(a)** in this case neither fraction can be simplified (that is, neither has any
> common factors in numerator and denominator);
>
> **(b)** if $\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{c}{d}$ are neighbor
> fractions, then $\displaystyle\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ is between them and is a neighbor fraction for
> both $\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{c}{d}$; moreover,
>
> **(c)** no fraction $\displaystyle\frac{e}{f}$ with positive integer $e$ and $f$ such
> that $f < b + d$ is between $\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{c}{d}$.

Parts (a) and (b) weren't too difficult, but I'm stuck on part (c).  I've included (a) and (b) in case they're related to the solution to (c).

Comment: Look up "Farey sequence".

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume $\frac{e}{f}$ is (strictly) between $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$.  Then $\left|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{e}{f}\right| + \left|\frac{e}{f}-\frac{c}{d}\right| = \left|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}\right| = \frac{1}{bd}$

But $\left|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{e}{f}\right| \geq \frac{1}{bf}$ and $\left|\frac{e}{f}-\frac{c}{d}\right|\geq \frac{1}{df}$.  So $\frac{1}{bf} + \frac{1}{df} \leq \frac{1}{bd}$.  Multiply both sides by $bdf$ and we get that $b+d\leq f$.

Comment: There is a geometric meaning to this, which is related to lattice points on the plane.  If $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are points on the plane, then $|ad-bc|$ is the area of the quadrilateral with points $(0,0)$, $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$ and $(a+c,b+d)$.  If $a,b,c,d$ are integers, and $|ad-bc| = 1$, this theorem essentially says that there is no lattice point in the inside of the quadrilateral.

Comment: In this case, I wrote "strictly' precisely because I wanted to be clear that I meant $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{e}{f}<\frac{c}{d}$ or $\frac{c}{d}<\frac{e}{f}<\frac{a}{b}$. @ArshJhaj The theorem is not true if you allow $e=c,f=d$. The first part of my line is true for $\frac{e}{f}=\frac{a}{b}$, but the next step: $$\left|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{e}{f}\right|\geq \frac{1}{bf}$$ is obviously not

Comment: Where does greater than sign come from? It must be equal to not greater than

Comment: There is no "greater than" sign, and lots of "greater than or equal to" signs, so you'll need to be more specific, @ShiranAbbasi

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right. Actually I am confused because first there were just "equal" signs then how did they become "greater than or equal to"?

Comment: The equality didn’t “become” $\geq.$ They arise from two different lines of reason. $$\left|\frac ab-\frac ef\right|=\frac{|af-be|}{bf}.$$ But if the fractions are not equal, $|af-be|\geq 1.$  The equality has to do with the conditions that $\frac ef$ is between $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd.$ In general, if $x$ is between $u$ and $v,$ then $|x-u|+|v-x|=|v-u|.$ @ShiranAbbasi