# Is there any way to determine whether an integer lies between 2 rational numbers without knowing them?

Tags: proof-explanation, fractions, integers

I want to know if there is a mathematical condition (not involving the floor function) for there to be an integer between 2 rational numbers $α$ & $β$. I know that $$β>[α]+1$$but I don't really know what to do with the Greatest Integer Function since I have no idea what the two numbers are.

**Source of the problem:**

> Show that there is no fraction $\frac{e}{f}$ where $f<b+d$ that lies
> between 2 **"neighbour fractions"** $\frac{a}{b}$ & $\frac{c}{d}$
> $(\frac{c}{d}-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{bd})$

So far, I've determined that $e$ can be any number in the interval $[f\cdot(\frac{a}{b}):f\cdot(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{1}{bd})]$ and want to find the values of $f$ for which an integer lies in the interval

Comment: The notation $[\alpha]$ has several possible meanings. Which of them is used in your assumption?

Comment: Greatest integer function; the one that rounds down α to the nearest integer

Comment: In other words, the floor function, right? Which you said you _don't_ want to involve, but if the very statement of the only property of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you know includes this function, how can one even imagine avoiding it?

Comment: I think I wrote that incorrectly. I just mentioned the condition involving the floor function to test whether an integer lies between α & β, but I can't really do anything with it since I don't know the numerical values of the two numbers (as mentioned in the source of the problem). I just want to know if there is any algebraic way to test it

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d,e,f$ positive integers in the source of the problem?

Comment: yes. I should have mentioned that too. Sorry about that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Neighbor fractions problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033628/neighbor-fractions-problem)

Comment: Not really. I have seen other proofs of this problem but I'm trying to solve it by another method

Answer (score 2):

Multiplied woith all denominators, your conditions are as follows:
$$
adf < ebd < cbf,\quad cb - ad = 1,\quad f < b+d.
$$
In particular,
$$
\alpha := (eb-af)d > 0\quad\text{and}\quad \beta := (cf-ed)b > 0.
$$
But also
$$
\alpha + \beta = (eb-af)d + (cf-ed)b = (cb-ad)f = f.
$$
Hence, we have $d|\alpha$, $b|\beta$ (and thus $d\le\alpha$, $b\le\beta$), and $\alpha + \beta = f < b+d\le \alpha+\beta$, which is absurd.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by _d|α,  b|β_?

Comment: $d$ divides $\alpha$ and $b$ divides $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you; I can easily understand the proof now. Could you elaborate more on how/why you defined α & β the way you did? I am trying to improve my proof writing skills. Even though I understand your proof, I wouldn't have ever attempted it this way

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH To be honest, I've just tried around in order to find something meaningful. I think it was kind of intuition. Sorry that I can't help you in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the possible application to "neighbour fractions", let's look at *sufficient conditions* on rational numbers $r,s$ that guarantee an integer $k$ strictly between them.

Obviously some knowledge about $r,s$ is needed because there are many pairs of rational numbers *without* an integer strictly between them.  Without using the floor function one can derive the "integer exists in between" from information about how far apart $r,s$ are.

If $|r-s| \gt 1$, then there is an integer $k$ strictly between $r$ and $s$.

If at least one of $r,s$ is itself not an integer, this can be improved to require merely $|r-s| \ge 1$.

Comment: These are sufficient but not necessary conditions right? Although I can't apply it to my problem, they are nonetheless helpful in gaining insight

Comment: We should be looking for some information regarding your $\alpha,\beta$ that constrains them from being a random pair of rational numbers.  Otherwise we have no hope of proving an integer exists between them.